# Spatstat, using the which.marks argument

Tags: r, spatstat

I have a point pattern that has marks. It was created using the connected.ppp function, also in the spatstat package. I want to plot only the points with marks equal to 2.
I thought that to do this, the which.marks argument needed to be used, however the output is still a plot including all the marks. The marks are definitely there because when I set use.marks = FALSE, the marks are no longer used.

```
plot.ppp(testconn, use.marks = TRUE, which.marks = 1)
```

I have included my point pattern object in case this is the issue

[image: testconn object]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument `which.marks` in `plot.ppp` is used for the case when you have an entire `data.frame` of marks. E.g. if marks is a `data.frame` with column names `mark1` and `mark2` you can choose which of these to use for plotting by setting e.g. `which.marks = "mark1"`.

To subset a point pattern you can use `subset`:

```
testconn1 <- subset(testconn, marks == "1", drop = TRUE)
```

Since your mark is a factor you have a multitype point pattern and you can split the pattern into a list of separate patterns using split:

```
testcon_list <- split(testconn)
```

And then the points of the first type are in `testconn_list[[1]]` or in `testconn_list[["1"]]` (not so relevant since your mark names are just 1, 2, ..., but with names like "mark1" etc. you could use `testconn_list[["mark1"]]` or `testconn_list$mark1`).